# Random Selection: not executing properly

Tags: autohotkey

My problem is about randomly select one on two options

```
one(){
MouseMove, 306, 266
}

two(){
MouseMove, 329, 378
}

rand(){
random, rand, two(), one()
return rand
}
```

the results always end at one()

Answer (score 3):

The random function only works if numbers can be generated as values for its parameters.

Try this:

```
F1::rand()

rand(){
    Array := ["one", "two"]
    random, rand, 1, 2
    return Array[rand]()
}

one(){
MouseMove, 306, 266
}

two(){
MouseMove, 329, 378
}
```

https://www.autohotkey.com/docs/Objects.htm#Usage_Simple_Arrays

Comment: To generalize, the Array can have an arbitrary number of items, and then use `random, rand, 1, Array.Length()` to pick one at random. Nice. I'll edit my answer to show how . . .

Answer (score 2):

You are close.  You are not setting proper values for min and max of Random. Use 0 and 1 and check via ternary operator:

```
one(){
MouseMove, 306, 266
}

two(){
MouseMove, 329, 378
}

random, rand, 0, 1
if (rand = 0) ? one() : two()
```

Hth

EDIT: for an arbitrary list of functions (as hinted by @user3419297):

```
one(){
MouseMove, 306, 266
}

two(){
MouseMove, 329, 378
}

another(){
MouseMove, 365, 437
}

more(){
MouseMove, 392, 403
}

Arr := ["one", "two", "another", "more"]
random, rand, 1, Arr.Length()
Arr[rand]()
```

Cool stuff!